# First error: Attempt to de-reference a null object

Tags: apex, batch, scheduled-apex, schedulebatch

I scheduled batch apex but get an error **First error: Attempt to de-reference a null object**, i have try to use if condition to catch the null parameter but no luck. I little bit curious here since i only use simple query to get the list of contact.

```
global class MonthlyEscrowStatementBatch implements Database.Batchable<sObject> {
global Database.QueryLocator start(Database.BatchableContext bc) {
    String query = 'SELECT Id FROM Contact WHERE Escrow_Account__c != null AND Account.Are_All_Opportunities_Closed__c = false';
    return Database.getQueryLocator(query);    
}

global void execute(Database.BatchableContext bc, List<Contact> ContactList){
    // process each batch of records
    if(ContactList.size()>0){
        for(Contact con : ContactList){
            if(con.id!=null)
                GenerateAndSubmitForApproval.GenerateAndSubmit(con.id, 'EscrowStatement', 'Escrow Monthly Statement', null);
        }  
    }

}    

global void finish(Database.BatchableContext bc){
}
}
```

Here is the GenerateAndSubmitApproval class to generate the document in salesforce

```
global without sharing class GenerateAndSubmitForApproval {
    webservice static string GenerateAndSubmit(string ContactID, string FileName, string type, string OppID)
    { 
        //Parameter initialisation
        PageReference pdf;
        if(type=='Monthly Escrow Statement'){
            pdf = Page.MonthlyEscrowStatement;
            pdf.getParameters().put('id',ContactID);
        }
        // the contents of the attachment from the pdf
        Blob body;

        //bypass test method for test classes
        if(!Test.isRunningTest())
            body = pdf.getContent();
        else
            body = Blob.valueOf('Some Text');

        try
        {
            //Generate content version with attached generated pdf
            ContentVersion v = new ContentVersion();
            v.versionData = body;
            v.title = FileName;
            v.pathOnClient ='/test.pdf'; //set the dummy path on client attribute (required)
            insert v;

            //if content version is create successfully

            if(v.id!=null) 
            {
                //get contact document id from created content verison
                List<ContentVersion> ContentVersions = [select ContentDocumentID from ContentVersion where id =: v.id];

                //if content document ids are present
                if(!ContentVersions.isEmpty())
                {
                    //share the content with related contact
                    ContentDocumentLink contentDocumentLinkObj = new ContentDocumentLink();
                    contentDocumentLinkObj.ContentDocumentId = ContentVersions.get(0).ContentDocumentID;
                    contentDocumentLinkObj.Visibility = 'AllUsers'; 
                    contentDocumentLinkObj.LinkedEntityId = ContactID;
                    contentDocumentLinkObj.ShareType='V';
                    insert contentDocumentLinkObj;

                    //Get Deposite Invoice ID
                    List<ContentWorkspace> CWList = [select id from ContentWorkspace where name = 'Generated Documents'];
                    if(!CWList.isEmpty())
                    {
                        //Share with Deposite Invoice
                        ContentWorkspaceDoc CWD = new ContentWorkspaceDoc(ContentWorkspaceId = CWList.get(0).id, ContentDocumentId = ContentVersions.get(0).ContentDocumentID);
                        insert CWD;

                        //Create Doc record
                        Doc__c D = new Doc__c(contact__c = ContactID, Content_Verison_Name__c = FileName, Content_ID__c = V.id, Status__c = 'Submitted For Approval');
                        if(type=='Monthly Escrow Statement'){
                            D.Type__c = 'Monthly Escrow Statement';
                        }

                        insert D;

                        return '1'; // PDF generated and submited for review successfully!
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            //if exception found
            return e.getMessage();
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: what is the line number?

Comment: @SantanuBoral, I only see the error in Apex Jobs. What should i do to get detailed error (line number)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The exception occurs here:

```
body = pdf.getContent();
```

`pdf` is currently null because you are checking if the `type` value is **'Monthly Escrow Statement'**.

```
//Parameter initialisation
PageReference pdf;
if(type=='Monthly Escrow Statement'){
    pdf = Page.MonthlyEscrowStatement;
    pdf.getParameters().put('id',ContactID);
}
```

You are setting the `type` to **'Escrow Monthly Statement'** instead of **'Monthly Escrow Statement'** in your batch class:

```
GenerateAndSubmitForApproval.GenerateAndSubmit(con.id, 'EscrowStatement', 'Escrow Monthly Statement', null);
```

This is a good example of when to use [**Constants**](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/langCon_apex_constants.htm) or [**Custom Labels**](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=cl_about.htm&type=5) to prevent errors like this from occuring.